# “I wake up lucidly - I think I’m awake -“?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading an interview today and came across this sentence that I don’t fully understand.

”I wake up lucidly – I think that I’m awake – and I go to the mirror and I scream and it’s a woman’s scream,” he says. “And then I wake up.”

what I don’t really understand is the “I wake up lucidly – I think that I’m awake –“ part.

is he saying it’s a lucid dream ? Like he becomes aware that he’s dreaming ??
or he thought he was awake but actually he wasn’t and still sleeping ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is he saying it’s a lucid dream ? Like he becomes aware that he’s
> dreaming ?? or he thought he was awake but actually he wasn’t and
> still sleeping ?

Given that it is difficult to describe states of consciousness when dreaming, I believe that he means he was aware that he was/had been dreaming and then was aware of "waking up". However he was mistaken and then actually woke up.

I personally understand the phenomenon because I have experienced it. I think such an experience is difficult to describe accurately in words.

However only the author knows truly what was meant.

Comment: I have dreamed that I woke up, then realised that I cannot have done so because of something counterfactual (e.g. because I think I am eleven years old).

Comment: Good answer but I think the original is poorly written. The meaning of his *I woke up lucidly* is *I had a clear sense of having awoken*, right? The *lucidly* sentence isn't the greatest way of putting that, I think.